# Spryker show new field added to merchant in product listing page

Tags: spryker

I am new to spryker, I have added a new field in spy_merchant table, I want to show that field in PLP page, I tried to do it, the value is displayed but if I update the values it is not get reflected, Can anyone help to update the value

Answer (score 1):

How did you update it ? Spryker has an asynchronous architecture and updates have to be published to storage and search tiers. Did you implement a ZED page or updated from db directly ? PLP is coming from elastic search as search tier, and you need to trigger an event by publish changes to update it.

Comment: implemented a zed page and updated it